# Remove the current row from table using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to remove the current row of the table by clicking the button using jquery 
i have tried this , please help me.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#medbtn").click(function () {
            var medicinelist = $("#medList").val();
            var selecttype = $("#TypeList").val();
            var qtyInput = $("#qty").val();
            var text = $("#medList").text();
            var data = '<tr> <td>' + text + ' </td> <td>' + selecttype + '</td> <td>' + qtyInput + '</td> <td><input type="button" value="X" id="remove"/></td> <input type="hidden" value=' + medicinelist + '/> </tr>';
            $('#listMedicine').append(data);

   i have tried this here, but not remove the row please help me thanks
            $("#remove").click(function () {
                $('data').remove();
            })
        });


            });
</script>
```

Comment: how to do this , please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

```
$("#listMedicine").on("click", ".remove", function () {
   $('data').remove();
});
```

Because `#remove` is dynamically created and DOM would not attach the click handler to it.. **Also use class `.remove` as id can not repeat.**

Comment: better close when there is dup